# R.id cannot be resolved on android ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

I am getting this strange error:

```
  R.id cannot be resolved
```

on lines:

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(view.R.id.webview);
 myWebView.loadUrl(s);
```

I tried to clean the project and restart it.
here is my code:

```
public class NewsActivity  extends ListActivity {
 public ReadXML ReadXML=new ReadXML();
 public  ArrayList<String> ynetList =new ArrayList<String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

for(int i=0;i<ReadXML.hadashotListItems.size();i++)
ynetList.add(ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(i).title+"\n"+ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(i).pubDate);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, ynetList));
    //  setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        String s=   ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(position).link;

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(view.R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl(s);
    //


      //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(((TextView)view).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
      );
    }}
```

my xml code is:
list_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>


<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: includin `xmlns:android` in parent Layout Container is enough. you don't need to include in it every tag.

Comment: Please stick to one problem per question. Otherwise when someone else is going through this question for an answer he will be throughly confused with multiple answers.. If you have multiple problems, shoot out different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `R.id cannot be resolved` means that the `R` class is not properly built or at least is not according to your file `list_item.xml` as it defines an `id`.

The probable causes are the following:

- Eclipse is lost and does not manage to build your project properly (this happens sometime): try to clean and rebuild your project (menu project/clean of Eclipse).
- Sometimes this is not sufficient either, so try to

  - clean you project
  - modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding a blank char in it
  - Close your project in Eclipse
  - Open it again
  - Re-clean it and build it

- Your file `list_item.xml` is not in the right directory. It should be in the directory `[project_root]/res/layout`
- You have an Android framework installation problem. Check in the menu "Windows/Android SDK and ADT manager" of Eclipse whether everything is fine.

Comment: did what you said its all look ok. but still get this message.

Comment: Wow... I'm sorry I have no other idea. I have favorited this question, I'm curious of knowing what it was

Comment: ok! did what you said no errors in lines! but now when it gets to  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() .I GET CLASS FILE EDITOR SOURSE NOT FOUND

Comment: I have a problem with my xml file I just dont know what is wrong with it you can see it in my privies comment.Now i created anther xml file called webview.xml and it looks like that: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"> <WebView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> </LinearLayout>

Comment: how can I use this xml with my old code? can ypu give me an example –

Comment: Well, the first thing to do before changing anything is to have the old code working.

Comment: the code is working but without  public void onItemClick method. how can I do the same thing but with webview.xml

Answer (score 0):

It should be just

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

No view before the `R`

Comment: are you getting some other errors before this? Can you clean and build the project?(after you make the above changes)

Comment: I tried to run the project without the pronlem lines and my program crashed because of the xml. it works only if xml without the view and witout the LinearLayout  like           <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: still the same error: id cannot be resolved or is not a field